# Sending mails via Gmail, 'bbc' not working - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel, gmail

I'm sending emails to many users and i want to add bbc, the sending itself is working but when I add `bbc` i'm getting this error

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Swift_Message' does not have a method 'bbc'
```

I'm posting the controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail(){


        $users = User::where('type','student')->pluck('email');


            foreach ($users as $user) {
                Mail::send('emails.test', ['user' => $users], function ($message) use ($users, $user) {
                    $message->from('mg.kvelichkov@gmail.com', 'МГ "Константин Величков"');
                    $message->to($user);
                    $message->bbc($user);
            });

        }

        return "Your email has been sent successfully";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Mail/Message.html#method_bcc) is `bcc` not `bbc`

Just change it to:

```
$message->bcc($user);
```

Comment: It's always the little things that get us :)  Glad to help